# How to import X.509 certificates into MacOS?

Tags: certificate

I have the file with X.509 certificates and the following preamble:

```
# This is a bundle of X.509 certificates of public Certificate
# Authorities.  It was generated from the Mozilla root CA list.
# These certificates are in the OpenSSL "TRUSTED CERTIFICATE"
# format and have trust bits set accordingly.
# An exception are auxiliary certificates, without positive or negative
# trust, but are used to assist in finding a preferred trust path.
# Those neutral certificates use the plain BEGIN CERTIFICATE format.
```

I tried to import it from command line but it fails:

```
$ sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain /Users/dzieciou/projects/mg/etc/pki/tls/certs/megabundle.crt

readFile: short read
***Error reading file /Users/dzieciou/projects/mg/etc/pki/tls/certs/
Error reading file /Users/dzieciou/projects/mg/etc/pki/tls/certs/megabundle.crt
```

I was able to import those certificates into Firefox on MacOS but Firefox does not use the system keychain.

Comment: Shouldn't you point to the cert (whole path to certificate) instead of pointing to the directory?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I've updated my question. You're right. It should be the file. But the problem persists.

Comment: Is there a specific application or tool that you want to use these certificates with? Adding them to the Keychain will affect most graphical browsers and applications but may not be found by open source tools.

Comment: @GrahamMiln I want it to be used with python setuptools, which in turn uses system provided certificate database: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/

Comment: Got it. I need to openssl x509 -in mycert.crt -out mycert.pem -outform PEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by converting it first to [PEM format](https://serverfault.com/questions/9708)…

```
openssl x509 -in megabundle.crt -out megabundle.pem -outform PEM
```

…and then importing using the command in the question.

Answer (score 1):

## Keychain Access

You can import a wide range of certificate formats with macOS's Keychain application.

1. Open **Applications > Utilities > Keychain Access.app**
2. Select the menu item: **File > Import Items…**

### Default Keychain

The imported items will appear in the current default keychain. If this is not what you want, be sure to change the default before importing.

Comment: An error has occurred. Unable to import an item. The contents of this item cannot be retrieved.